# Pybrain bidirectional net class only supports feedforward network

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain, deep-learning, lstm

According to this

https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/blob/1dd5086a51c3c98497ef85b31178588a89d8951e/pybrain/structure/networks/bidirectional.py

the class only supports feedforward net?
How can I implement bidirection-LSTM recurrent network?

Comment: what is the question ?